# Como registro Asp.NET Versión 4.0 en Internet information Services (IIS) en Windows 10?

Tags: asp.net, iis, cmd, windows10

Hola amigos developers :)

Tengo un problema , instale **Windows 10** en mi PC, y también el **Internet Information Services (IIS)** desde el panel de control->Programas->Añadir funcionalidades adicionales , y tambien instale **Visual Studio 2012**.

Hasta ahí todo bien, incluso se instaló **Asp.net 4.0** pero al momento que quiero registrar **Asp.net 4.0** con el **IIS** mediante la linea de comandos **(CMD)** ingresando el comando de siempre **aspnet_regiis -i**, me despliega un mensaje de error que me indica **Esta opción no es compatible con la versión del sistema operativo**

[image: Error que me aparace]

Por favor si alguien puede ayudarme para registrar el **Asp.net** con el **IIS** le agradezco mucho ya que necesito publicar un proyecto con esas caracteristicas.

Muchas Gracias < :) >

Comment: Antes de poner una respuesta, quizás sea recomendable remarcar que en el propio mensaje de error que nos muestras, ya incluye la respuesta que buscas!. En ese mensaje te indica que debes instalarlo a través de  _activar o desactivar las características de windows_ y te proporciona un enlace de consulta

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta , me falto mencionar que ya hice lo que indica en la imagen pero sin ningún resultado positivo , por eso realizo la pregunta, porque desconozco como solucionar mi problema , gracias de todas formas :)

Comment: Nada, yo lo decía por si acaso. No fuera a ser que entre tanto texto "aprejuntado" se te hubiera pasado por alto. Una cuestión, si seguiste el procedimiento que te indica el mensaje, y activaste ASP.NET 4.0 para IIS8.0 a través de las características de windows. Cual es el indicador de que no se encuentre funcionando? Es decir, cual es el error con el que te encontraste después del proceso?

Comment: El error es que el Asp.net 4.0 no aparece en el IIS  cuando quiero realizar una aplication pool para mi proyecto. Y me quede en las mismas :)

Comment: Mira, puedes mirar aquí, al parecer tiene que ver después de haber instalado el Framework 4.6: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/dialog-box-may-be-displayed-to-users-when-opening-projects-in-microsoft-visual-studio-after-installation-of-microsoft-net-framework-4-6/

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate de tener habilitado todo lo que aparece en la imagen debajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:** En tu caso debe ser ASP.Net 4.6 o 4.7 si ya tienes instalado el creators update.

Comment: Gracias , sabes que ya hice lo que me comentaste pero sigo sin lograr hacer que el asp.net 4.0 aparezca en el IIS para realizar una aplication pool con asp.net 4.0 ,, talvez otra idea , gracias igual :)

Comment: @Barckl3y Lamentablemente no conozco ningún otro método (más allá de ponerte a jugar con `dism` y lanzar tu mismo los paquetes de características). Mi "apuesta" es que éste es el procedimiento adecuado pero no se ha realizado bien por alguna circunstancia, por que no pruebas a desinstalar las características, reiniciar y volverlas a instalar? Si eso tampoco puedes probar a forzarlo con `dism` ejecutando este comando desde la consola `dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45 /all` por probar...